# How do you calculate age from a birth date in MS Access?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

How do you calculate the current age of an individual based off of their birthdate in MS Access?

I've tried `=DateDiff("yyyy", [DOB], Date())`

But that only returns how old they *will* be that calendar year, so if they haven't had their birthday yet then it's inacurate. How can you calculate their age based of what calendar day it is?

Answer (score 1):

There's a function you can add to your code that does this easily for you. Go to Visual Basic, insert a new module and then paste in the following code:

```
Function Age(varDOB As Variant, Optional varAsOf As Variant) As Variant
    'Purpose:   Return the Age in years.
    'Arguments: varDOB = Date Of Birth
    '           varAsOf = the date to calculate the age at, or today if missing.
    'Return:    Whole number of years.
    Dim dtDOB As Date
    Dim dtAsOf As Date
    Dim dtBDay As Date  'Birthday in the year of calculation.

    Age = Null          'Initialize to Null

    'Validate parameters
    If IsDate(varDOB) Then
        dtDOB = varDOB

        If Not IsDate(varAsOf) Then  'Date to calculate age from.
            dtAsOf = Date
        Else
            dtAsOf = varAsOf
        End If

        If dtAsOf >= dtDOB Then      'Calculate only if it's after person was born.
            dtBDay = DateSerial(Year(dtAsOf), Month(dtDOB), Day(dtDOB))
            Age = DateDiff("yyyy", dtDOB, dtAsOf) + (dtBDay > dtAsOf)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

You can then simply create a control and set the control source to `=Age([name of the filed with the birth date])` and the function will accurately calculate ages.

---

<sup>Code Provided by Allen Browne. http://allenbrowne.com/func-08.html</sup>